# Can't instantiate multiple tinymce editors in different EPiServer gadgets

Tags: tinymce, episerver-9

I'm developing two gadgets in an EPiServer CMS 9.2 site using the *old* (MVC Controller) style gadgets. Both gadgets need a rich text editor. I've wired in TinyMCE and it work's fine the first time one of the gadgets instantiates the editor but then fails silently after that.

The code to instantiate the element is triggered using the `GadgetAttribute.ClientScriptInitMethod` and my init function looks like:

```
MyGadget.init = function (e, gadget) {
    $(gadget.element).find('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
        theme: "modern"
    });
};
```

On subsequent invocations even in the same gadget, the call to `tinymce()` completes without error but the editor is not present in the DOM (as the element before the related `<textarea>` and the underlying `<textarea>` is not visible.

What could be causing this? How might I fix it?

Comment: Are you using your own download of the editor or trying to use Episerver's? Epi recommends not using theirs for putting an editor into your own interfaces: https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/Episerver-CMS/9/Editing/Customizing-the-TinyMCE-editor/#rollyourown

Comment: @egandalf I've got my own copy in my module directory

Comment: Have you tested your code outside of the dashboard? E.g. set up an empty page and see if you can instantiate it twice without anything else possibly getting in the way? Always helps to remove what variables you can when testing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to call the init function for tinymce and pass a selector.

Something along these lines perhaps? (untested)

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#gadgetElementId textarea.tinymce',
});
```

[More info here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/multiple-editors/)

Comment: I'm using the jQuery plugin ` $(gadget.element).find('textarea.tinymce').` targets the specific element I think.